# How to use variables in tests that were assigned with values at beforeAll() hook

Tags: typescript, jestjs, automated-tests, each, playwright

I want to assign a bunch of variables with values at `beforeAll()` hook and then use them in `test.each([])`, but all I get is undefined instead of actual values.

But when I try to access the same variables in normal `test()`, it turns out, that my variables have actual values and are not undefined.

Is there an any way to assign variables with values and then use them in `test.each([])`?

```
let movieId: string;
let serialId: string;

describe('Video page tests', () => {

  beforeAll(async () => {
    movieId = await videos.CreateMovie();
    serialId = await videos.CreateSerial();
  });

test.each([
    ['Deletes movie', movieId],
    ['Deletes serial', serialId],
  ])('%s', async(caseTitle, entityId) => {
    reporter.description(`${caseTitle}`);

    await videos.DeleteContent(entityId); //entityId is undefined
  })

test('Deletes movie', async() => {
    reporter.description(`Deletes movie`);

    await videos.DeleteContent(movieId); //movieId is correct
  })
```

Comment: You can't. The `beforeAll` is still run at test _execution_ time, not test _discovery_ time (when `test.each` is evaluated). That's why the ID is correct inside the test, that runs _after_ `beforeAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that I can't use variables at `test.each`, that vere assigned at `beforeAll` hook, so I came up with a solution to my problem

```
let content: string[] = [];
describe('Video page tests', () => {

  beforeAll(async () => {
    content.push(await videos.CreateMovie());
    content.push(await videos.CreateSerial());
  });

test.each([
    ['Deletes movie', 0],
    ['Deletes serial', 1],
  ])('%s', async(caseTitle, entityId) => {
    reporter.description(`${caseTitle}`);

    await videos.DeleteContent(content[entityId]);
  })
```